# Hankel Singular Values for diagonal state-space model

Tags: singular-values, hankel-matrices

Let (A,B,C) be a **diagonal** and stable discrete-time LTI state space model:
\begin{align*}x(k+1)&=Ax(k)+Bu(k),\\ y&= Cx(k)\end{align*} with A being a diagonal matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 &0  &\cdots&0  \\
 0  & \lambda_2&\cdots&0\\
 \vdots&  & \ddots &\vdots\\
0& 0&\ldots &\lambda_n 
\end{bmatrix}
Can we compute singular values of the Hankel matrix $\sigma_{i}(H)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$ of this system in a closed-form, in terms of model matrices A,B,C, exploiting the diagonal A structure?
Recalling that the Hankel matrix is of the form $H= \begin{bmatrix}
CB &CAB  &CA^2B&\cdots  \\
 CAB&CA^2B  & CA^3B&\cdots \\
 CA^2B& CA^3B & CA^4B&\cdots \\
\vdots& \vdots&\vdots & 
\end{bmatrix} $